# Why my table have no border when printed using DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use [DataTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/customisation.html) to display my database output. I use the print button on the datatable to print the table. It open another window with the table to be printed. But, the table border is not displayed properly.

In page 1, the far right border is missing. In page 2 and other page, the table border is not even displayed.

This is my datatable script:

```
$('.dataTables-example').DataTable({

    pageLength  : 25,
    responsive  : true,
    dom         : '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    buttons     : [
                    {   extend          : 'copyHtml5'},
                    {
                        extend          : 'excel', 
                        title           : "TEST PAGE" },
                    {
                        extend          : 'pdf', 
                        title           : "TEST PAGE"},
                    {
                        extend          : 'print',
                        orientation     : 'landscape',
                        title           : 'TEST PAGE',
                        autoPrint       : false,
                        message         : 'UP MESSAGE',
                        messageBottom   : 'BOTTOM MESSAGE', 
                        customize       : function (win){
                            $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                            $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                            $(win.document.body).find('table').css('font-size', 'inherit'); 

                            $(win.document.body).find('table tr').css('border','1px solid black');  

                            $(win.document.body).find('tbody tr').each(function(c){

                                $(this).find('td').css('vertical-align','middle');

                                $(this).find('td:eq(0)').css('text-align','right'); 
                                $(this).find('td:eq(5)').css('text-align','right'); 
                                $(this).find('td:eq(6)').css('text-align','right'); 
                            });
                        }

                    }
    ] 
});
```

Comment: Can you check the new page source code and check Data table css is there or not ?

Comment: I use the new datatable css and the border is missing. When I use the old one, the border is displayed but print button is not styled

Comment: Try to use same version of js and css, if print button not styled create new css class for the button .

Comment: can you show me? also the pagination button is not styled